# Chromecast ExpandedControllerActivity crashes: Attempt to write to field CastSeekBar on a null object reference

Tags: android, chromecast

I am working on a team in a large Android project with multiple flavors of the app. We have two different implementations of chromecast since he two flavors have different UI and requirements. Currently I'm trying to create a new ExpandedControllerActivity on my flavor of the app to be more in line with standard implementation.

But I am getting a crash when trying to open the expanded controller during runtime, and I just can't figure out what I am doing wrong from the log message.

```
class MyAppChromecastExpandedControllerActivity : ExpandedControllerActivity() {
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.actions, menu)
        CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(this, menu, R.id.media_route_menu_item)
        return true
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="dk.myapp.chromecast.MyAppChromecastExpandedControllerActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:theme="@style/MyAppCastControlsStyle"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="dk.myapp.SynopsisActivity" />
</activity>

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.OPTIONS_PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME"
    android:value="dk.myapp.chromecast.CastOptionsProvider" />
```

Style:

```
<style name="MyAppCastControlsStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="castExpandedControllerToolbarStyle">
        @style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar
    </item>
    <item name="castControlButtons">@array/cast_expanded_controller_control_buttons</item>
</style>

<array name="cast_expanded_controller_control_buttons">
    <item>@id/cast_button_type_empty</item>
    <item>@id/cast_button_type_empty</item>
    <item>@id/cast_button_type_empty</item>
    <item>@id/cast_button_type_empty</item>
</array>
```

Log Message:

```
2021-05-31 10:40:06.651 1342-1342/dk.myapp.app.debug E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: dk.myapp.app.debug, PID: 1342
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{dk.myapp.app.debug/dk.myapp.chromecast.MyAppChromecastExpandedControllerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.widget.CastSeekBar$zza com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.widget.CastSeekBar.zzwt' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3114)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3257)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.widget.CastSeekBar$zza com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.widget.CastSeekBar.zzwt' on a null object reference
    at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.uicontroller.UIMediaController.bindSeekBar(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework@@18.1.0:71)
    at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.widget.ExpandedControllerActivity.onCreate(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework@@18.1.0:94)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7327)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7318)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3094)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3257) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

Since the error mentions MyAppChromecastExpandedControllerActivity, which is mine, I reckon it is using my ExpandedControllerActivity, but then I don't see why there should be a problem with the SeekBar then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Struggled with it for a week, posted a question on stackoverflow, then debugged the problem in half an hour.

Turns out the custom layout for the old ExpandedController was called "cast_expanded_controller_activity", which is the same name as the default chromecast layout. So apparently the custom layout overrode the default layout, resulting in the crash when the new non-custom ExpandedController couldn't find the seekbar on the layout.

So if anyone else runs into similar problems: make sure that none of your controls or views has a name that overrides the defaults.

Comment: Yeah, add the same behaviour, they changed the layout. I did as U previously, so just copied the new Layout from library and re add my RecyclerView to display a list of Videos